# How to get specific word in a whole string?

Tags: android, string

I am creating and android app that randomly generates any category, I would like to get the given random category word. This is the example string

> String="The category Animals that starts with a letter J";

or

> String="The category Colors that starts with a letter V";

I need to get the word **Animals** or **Colors** every random String is generated

Comment: Your pattern of string is same? for all the string?

Comment: does the word always come after category?

Comment: yes it does and before the word "that"

Comment: String resultCat=yourString.split(" ")[2];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use Matcher and Pattern -

```
 String input = "The category Animals that starts with a letter J";
            Matcher m1 = Pattern.compile("^The category (.*) that starts with a letter (.*)$").matcher(input);
            if(m1.find()) {
                String _thirdWord = m1.group(1); // Animals
                String _lastWord  = m1.group(2); // J
                System.out.println("Third word : "+_thirdWord);
                System.out.println("Last Word : "+_lastWord);

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use regex.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\bcategory\\s+(\\S+)").matcher(str);
while(m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group(1));
 }
```

**OR**

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\bcategory\\s)\\S+").matcher(str);
while(m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group());
 }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, but can you please elaborate it more, what does the letters b, s, and S stands for in here `"(?<=\\bcategory\\s)\\S+"`

Answer (score 1):

A not so advanced solution, but easy to understand:

```
    public void findCategory() {
    String string = "The category Colors that starts with a letter V";

    String[] split = string.split(" ");
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        if ("category".equals(split[i])) {
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(split[i + 1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it might fix your issue

```
String string = "The category Colors that starts with a letter V";

String[] ar = string.split(" ");

System.out.println(ar[2]);
```